# How do I chop up a string into parts and read them as a hexadecimal value?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, integer, hex

So I want to build a simple calculator program with hexadecimals as their input. But the input would also contain both the operation and the numbers to operate. The first two hexadecimals would be the math operations which are 01 = addition, 02 = subtraction, 03 = multiplication, and 04 = division, and the following four or more hexadecimals would be two hexadecimals (a max value of FF) to operate on.

An example input would be **010306** where it would be the operation **03 + 06** since 01 is addition and 03 and 06 being the numbers to operate on. I can manage implementing the calculator part but I can't seem to figure out how to chop up strings by 2 and convert them to hexadecimals. I kind of know a way but I do now know the correct syntax. Here is my thought code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    string input = "010306";
    
    int exampleHex[input.length()/2];
    
    for(int index = 0; index < exampleHex.length(); index+2){
        exampleHex[index] = stoi(input[index] + stoi(input[index+1]), 0, 16);
    }
    /*
     * or somethiing like this to somehow get
     * int exampleHex[] = {01, 03, 06}
     */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int exampleHex[input.length()/2];` is invalid C++, (VLA extension), use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: can I use std::deque instead of std::vector? But then I would still have to figure out how to chop the string by 2...

Comment: yes, `std::vector` is the *default* container, but other can be good/better too.

Comment: How would I go about on the chopping of the string by 2s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the splitting, doing something like this should produce the result you want, so long as it's always a consistent 2 (or whatever) characters.

```
std::string nums = "010306";

int splitLength = 2;

std::vector<std::string> substrings;

for (int i = 0; i < nums.length(); i += splitLength)
{
    substrings.push_back(nums.substr(i, splitLength));
}
```

Giving the resulting vector `{ "01", "03", "06" }`

Comment: This one right here! Many thanks for your help mate! That concludes my almost-a-week headache. Cheers!